# Axis2 + maven ClassFormatError when trying to consume service

Tags: web-services, maven, axis

I've created with Axis2 XMLBeans (Version 1.6.2) a client to connect some CRM Dynamics webservices. The client works perfectly fine when I launch it as a standalone project, but when I integrate it into the maven structure of the project and I try to consume the service, I get the following error:

> ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-13][render_portlet_jsp:154]
>   java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 4022320623 in
>   class file
>   schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/system/sC40263DCBC25A143E59FC252DB52E714/TypeSystemHolder
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2889)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
>     at
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:769)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.schemas.crm._2007.webservices.RetrieveDocument.(RetrieveDocument.java:19)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.schemas.crm._2007.webservices.RetrieveDocument$Factory.newInstance(RetrieveDocument.java:147)

I've created the Axis code who's giving the error via Maven with the following plugin:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <packageName>myPackage</packageName>
                            <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/CrmService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Any idea what is happening? The error indicates normally that the class is corrupted, but I've generated several times (and with different versions of Axis2) and the result is the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the solution. In order to include the generated classes into the jar, I've added this lines:

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/axis2/wsdl2code/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/axis2/wsdl2code/src</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

After changing the filtering of the resources directory to false, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, I generated an axis 2 client with xmlbeans and when testing it gave me the same error, I looked in many places for a possible solution and this was the only one that worked for me.
The web client is built in a maven module for another web application inside a jar as a dependency.

[image]

at the end modifying the pom file to add the filter equal to false it worked

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code screenshots; copy & paste the code here as *text*.